# How to integrate, $\int e^{\frac{2}{y}}(1-\frac{2}{y})dy$

Tags: calculus

$\int e^{\frac{2}{y}}(1-\frac{2}{y})dy$

Let, $\frac{2}{y}=t$

then, $0=t\frac{dy}{dt}+y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Find an expression for
$$
\int e^x\cdot x\,\mathrm dx
$$
using integration by parts.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Use integration by parts to get:
$$\int e^{\frac{2}{y}}dy=ye^{\frac{2}{y}}-\int y(\frac{-2}{y^2})e^{\frac{2}{y}}dy$$
Thus:
$$\int e^{\frac{2}{y}}dy+\int y(\frac{-2}{y^2})e^{\frac{2}{y}}dy=ye^{\frac{2}{y}}$$